# Method error while executing the Testng file

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters, testng

I am a beginner to java. Kindly help me in the below code,

```
@Test(priority=1)
  public void signup(String emailvalue) {
  System.out.println("Page Title: " +driver.getTitle()); 

  driver.findElement(By.id("proprietorName")).sendKeys("Im Owner");

  driver.findElement(By.id("businessName")).sendKeys("Pharmacy By Selenium");

  driver.findElement(By.id("proprietorMobileNo")).sendKeys("1236547890");

  driver.findElement(By.id("website")).sendKeys("http://www.google.com");

  driver.findElement(By.id("businessUserEmail")).sendKeys("emailvalue");

  driver.findElement(By.id("businessUserPassword")).sendKeys("123456");

  driver.findElement(By.id("confirmpass")).sendKeys("123456");

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-12 mgbt-xs-10 mgtp-20']//div[@class='vd_checkbox']//label[@for='checkbox-2']")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.id("submit-register")).click();

  try
  {
      if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-danger vd_hidden']")).isDisplayed())
      {
          driver.findElement(By.id("businessUserEmail")).clear();

          driver.findElement(By.id("businessUserEmail")).sendKeys("emailvalue");

          driver.findElement(By.id("submit-register")).click();
      }

  }
  catch(NoSuchElementException e)
  {
      System.out.println("Given inputs are accepted.");
  }


      switch(emailvalue)
      {   

    case "0": 
          emailvalue = "daniel@xxxx.in";
          break;

    case "1":
          emailvalue = "daniel1@xxxx.in";
          break;

    case "2":
          emailvalue = "daniel2@xxxx.in";
          break;

    case "3":
          emailvalue = "daniel3@xxxx.in";
          break;

    case "4":
          emailvalue = "daniel4@xxxx.in";
          break;      

    case "5":
          emailvalue = "daniel5@xxxx.in";
          break;          

      }

}
  }
```

When i execute the above code, i got the following error,

```
Method signup requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:198)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:373)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:450)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Where have you called the method? May be you didnot suppy the argument..

Comment: no where.. plz help me to correct on this..

Comment: Do you really need the `@Test(priority=1)` with priority=1? If not try to remove (priority=1) and just let `@Test`

Comment: you have to call it somewhere and pass the argument  or use a dataprovider or parameterised testng.xml to provide the parameter to that method. How are you running this ?

Comment: @bryce, i had executed by removing "priority" and still same error.

Comment: @shamik, using normal testng method, i was trying to execute..
ALT+SHT+X+N

Comment: @DanielPrabhu Check my answer below and accept it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass arguments to the test method. That could be done in multiple ways. Like using dataprovider classes or  running using testng.xml and passing as argument. You can createa a testng.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<suite allow-return-values="false" configfailurepolicy="skip" data-provider-thread-count="10" group-by-instances="false" junit="false" name="FullSuite" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" thread-count="5" verbose="1">

   <test allow-return-values="false" group-by-instances="false" id="apiversion1" junit="false" name="TestExecutionWithAPIversion1" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">
      <parameter name="emailvalue" value="0"/>
      <classes>
         <class name="com.test.scripts.yourclassnamewithcorrectpackage/>

      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

and then modify your method to read the parameter you are passing

```
@Parameters({ "emailvalue" })
@Test(priority=1)
  public void signup(String emailvalue) {
  System.out.println("Page Title: " +driver.
....


}
```

And then run the file using testng.xml. You can right click go to runas - > run configurations - > Suite -> chose the testng.xml in your project. For more details read [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml)

Comment: i tried with the above code, but, it fails again :(

Comment: using run,  run configurations - > Suite -> chose the testng.xml

org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 7; The value of attribute "name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
 at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)

Comment: <test allow-return-values="false" group-by-instances="false" id="apiversion1" junit="false" name="TestExecutionWithAPIversion1" preserve-order="true" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">
      <parameter name="emailvalue" value="daniel@gmail.com"/>
      <classes>
         <class name="com.test.scripts.GP_webregister.gp_register/>

Comment: my xml file.. plz see

Comment: if i run the code by run-> runas -> testng, i got the following result,

Parameter 'emailvalue' is required by Test on method signup but has not been marked Optional or defined
in C:\Users\Beyond\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1285547681\testng-customsuite.xml

Comment: @DanielPrabhu your xml has some error it says . 

Do one thing you can put an optional value as well like this  and then run as testng class.

public void signup(@Optional("xyz@gmail.com")String emailvalue ){

}

Comment: @DanielPrabhu your xml is not correct. I dont see you closing the class name with this  ' " ' .. please check my xml

Comment: @DanielPrabhu Please accept it as answer if it solved your issue.